# Castle Windsor WCF Facility not setting Username Credentials

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor

I am unable to see why the WCF Facility is failing to set the user-name credentials on my client configuration. Could anyone see where I am going wrong?

When the IService is resolved from the container the ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName and Password are null. As are the Endpoint equivilents. None of the credentials references are set at all and all remain null values.

```
container
   .Register(
        Component
            .For<IService>()
            .ImplementedBy<ServiceClient>()
                .AsWcfClient(
                     new DefaultClientModel
                          {
                              Endpoint = WcfEndpoint
                                  .FromConfiguration("binding"),
                          }
                 .Credentials(
                        new UserNameCredentials(
                            "username", 
                            "password"))));
```

The binding and endpoint configuration is being picked up correctly from the app.config file - it is purely the authentication that I need to resolve.

for completeness:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="binding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://___________________" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="binding" contract="Namespace.Class" name="binding" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```